# How can I infer the value of an object from a conditional key?

Tags: typescript

For example, I want to write a tree traversal function:

```js
// Pick keys from an object if the value is T[] type
type SubTreesField<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends T[] ? K : never;

function traverse<T, K extends keyof T>(
  t: T,
  key: SubTreesField<T, K>,
  cb: (t: T) => void
) {
  const arr = t[key]; // The 'arr' type is T[SubTreesField<T, K>] instead of T[]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript can't infer the type of `T[K]` based on that conditional. That's far too complicated for it to figure out. You need to define a more explicit constraint for `T` so Typescript knows what it looks like. In fact, you don't need a conditional at all for this. Try:

```
function traverse<T extends { [k in K]: T[] }, K extends keyof T>(
  t: T,
  key: K,
  cb: (t: T) => void
) {
  const arr: T[] = t[key]
}
```